# Show that the stabilizer is a prime subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, group-actions

We define a subgroup $H$ as being *convex* if $g\in H\implies h\in H$ for all $1\leq h\leq g$. A convex subgroup $P$ is prime if for any two convex subgroups $X,Y$: $X\cap Y \subseteq P$ implies that $X\subseteq P$ or $Y\subseteq P$.

Say that $G$ is a latttice ordered subgroup of $A(S)$, the automorphisms of a totally ordered set $S$. Let $G_\alpha$ be the stabilizer of some $\alpha \in S$, i.e. $\{g:\alpha g=\alpha\}$.

Glass' *Partially Ordered Groups* states that $G_\alpha$ is "obviously" a prime (convex) subgroup of $G$, but I don't understand why.

I don't even see why it needs to be convex - while I can't come up with a counter example, I can't see any reason why if $g$ stabilizes $\alpha$ and $h\leq g$ then $h$ must also stabilize $\alpha$.

Comment: The definition of a prime (convex) subgroup can be found in one of OP's [earlier questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/424516/26306).

Comment: Thanks @dtldarek, I've added the definition in above for easier reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $1 \leq h \leq g$ then $x \leq h(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in S$ by definition of the lattice order on $A(S)$. Taking $x=\alpha$ we get $\alpha \leq h(\alpha) \leq \alpha$, as was to be shown ($G_a$ is convex).

Now suppose $h \wedge k =1$ for $h,k \in G$. Then $\min(h(\alpha),k(\alpha))=1(\alpha)$, that is,either $h(\alpha)=\alpha$ or $k(\alpha)=\alpha$. Thus either $h$ or $k$ in $G_a$. Hence $G_a$ is prime by Glass's Lemma 3.3.3.ii on page 37. This completes the proof of the “clearly” claim on page 140 (next to a proof of Holland's theorem).

The lattice order of $A(S)$ is described on the first page of Holland (1963) and also as Example 1.3.19 in Glass's *Partially Ordered Groups*. The prime part might also be proven in that paper (check the "tower" stuff), but this is not my area.

- Holland, Charles.
  “The lattice-ordered groups of automorphisms of an ordered set.”
  Michigan Math. J. 10 (1963) 399–408.
  MR[158009](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=158009)
  DOI:[10.1307/mmj/1028998976](http://dx.doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1028998976)

Comment: Cor 3.3.7 of Glass might be the tower/prime equivalence.

Comment: Thanks Jack! To clarify, is the construction in 1.3.19 the only way we can order $\text{Aut}(S,<)$? It seems like we could have even a trivial reordering like $f\leq g\leftrightarrow f(x)\geq g(x)$ which would make the result not true.

Comment: @Xodarp: I suspect many orderings are possible, but that this is the ordering intended. $\ell$-subgroup is slightly different from “$\ell$-group that is a subgroup” and implies the subgroup is a sublattice as well. Without those compatibilities, I'm pretty sure you can come up with counterexamples (quite possibly with totally ordered groups acting on themselves regularly).

Comment: For future readers, I think I've thought of a counter example: consider $\mathbb R^+$ under the usual ordering and automorphisms are ordered $f\leq g$ if $f(2)\leq g(2)$. Let $f(x)=3x/2,g(x)=x^2$; clearly $1\leq f\leq g$ and $g$ stabilizes 1, but $f$ does not.